# Tab item title in tablayout displaying not well arranged

Tags: java, android

I am working on an existing project where tablayout is integrated but the tab items title are not displaying well arranged. Below is screenshot of what it looks like and also a screenshot of how i want it to look like

[image]

This is actually how i want the tab item title displaying
[image]

This is my xml file code snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".salesinvoice.fragments.SalesInvoiceInstanceFragment">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="salesRecord"
            type="com.mainsoftdc.costoma.salesinvoice.entities.SalesRecord" />

        <variable
            name="eventHandler"
            type="com.mainsoftdc.costoma.salesinvoice.eventhandlers.SalesInvoiceInstanceEventHandler" />

        <import type="com.mainsoftdc.costoma.shared.utils.DecimalFormatter" />

        <import type="com.mainsoftdc.costoma.shared.utils.MoneyFormatter" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/sales_instance_top_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorGreyLight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_xs"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_xs"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_edit_sale_instance_customer_name"
                style="@style/BtnTextPrimarySmNoPadding"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="@{() -> eventHandler.editCustomerName()}"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_xs"
                android:text="@string/sales_instance_edit_customer_name"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_12sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_close_sale_instance"
                style="@style/BtnTextPrimarySmNoPadding"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="@{() -> eventHandler.closeSaleInstance()}"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_xs"
                android:text="@string/sales_instance_close_invoice"
                android:textColor="@color/colorRed"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_12sp"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/sales_product_list_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_xs"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_xxs"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_xs"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/no_padding"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/sales_instance_top_layout">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sales_instance_items"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_xs"
                android:text="@string/sales_instance_all_items"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_add_item_to_sales"
                style="@style/BtnSecondarySmOutlined"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minWidth="0dp"
                android:minHeight="0dp"
                android:onClick="@{() -> eventHandler.addItemToSalesBook()}"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_xs"
                android:text="@string/sales_instance_add_item"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_10sp"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_24dp"
                app:iconSize="14dp"
                app:iconTint="@color/colorAccent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sales_instance_product_list"
            style="@style/ListPage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/sales_instance_buttons"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/sales_product_list_header"
            >

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/sales_instance_product_list_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_md"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sales_instance_sales_summary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorGreyLight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_sm"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_sm"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_xs"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_xs"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/sales_instance_buttons">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextLabel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/sales_instance_total_volume"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@{DecimalFormatter.format(salesRecord.totalProductsSold)}"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextLabel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:text="@string/sale_instance_total_value"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:text="@{MoneyFormatter.format(salesRecord.totalSellingPrice)}"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sales_instance_buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_xs"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/no_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_xs"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/no_padding"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/sale_instance_quote_btn"
                style="@style/BtnTextPrimarySm"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_md"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/xml_drawable_rectangle_border"
                android:onClick="@{() ->eventHandler.saveAsQuote()}"
                android:text="@string/sales_instance_quote_btn"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_14sp" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/sale_instance_checkout_print_btn"
                style="@style/BtnTextPrimarySm"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_md"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/xml_drawable_rectangle_border"
                android:onClick="@{() ->eventHandler.captureAmountPaidAndCompleteSales()}"
                android:text="@string/sale_instance_proceed_to_checkout"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_14sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

This is my Adapter Code snippet:

```
public class SalesInvoicePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private SalesInvoiceViewModel salesInvoiceViewModel;

    private List<SalesRecord> activeSalesRecords = new ArrayList<>();

    @SuppressLint("UseSparseArrays")
    public SalesInvoicePagerAdapter(final Fragment ownerFragment, SalesInvoiceViewModel salesViewModel) {

        super(ownerFragment.getChildFragmentManager());
        salesInvoiceViewModel = salesViewModel;

        salesInvoiceViewModel.getActiveSalesRecords().observe(ownerFragment, new Observer<List<SalesRecord>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<SalesRecord> salesRecords) {
                activeSalesRecords = salesRecords;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        salesInvoiceViewModel.newSaleAlert.observe(ownerFragment, new Observer<SalesRecord>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable SalesRecord salesRecord) {
                Log.i("New Alert", String.valueOf(activeSalesRecords.size()));
                activeSalesRecords.add(salesRecord);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        salesInvoiceViewModel.saleClosedAlert.observe(ownerFragment, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Integer instancePosition) {
                if(activeSalesRecords.size() > 0) {
                    activeSalesRecords.remove((int) instancePosition);


                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });

        salesInvoiceViewModel.saleUpdatedAlert.observe(ownerFragment, new Observer<Pair<Integer, SalesRecord>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Pair<Integer, SalesRecord> updatedSalesRecordPair) {
                if(updatedSalesRecordPair != null) {
                    activeSalesRecords.remove((int) updatedSalesRecordPair.first);
                    activeSalesRecords.add(updatedSalesRecordPair.first, updatedSalesRecordPair.second);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Log.i("Set Current", String.valueOf(activeSalesRecords.size()));
        if (activeSalesRecords.size() > 0) {
            Fragment fragment = new SalesInvoiceInstanceFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(IntentExtras.SALES_INSTANCE_GUID, activeSalesRecords.get(i).getGuid());
            bundle.putInt(IntentExtras.SALES_INSTANCE_FRAGMENT_POSITION, i);

            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return fragment;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return activeSalesRecords.size();
    }

    // @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Log.i("NAME: ", activeSalesRecords.get(position).getCustomerName());
        Log.i("Page Title: ", activeSalesRecords.get(position).getCustomerName());
        return activeSalesRecords.get(position).getCustomerName();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

This is my Fragment file code snippet:

```
public class SalesInvoiceFragment extends BaseFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = SalesInvoiceFragment.class.getName();

    private FragmentSalesInvoiceBinding dataBinding;

    private SalesInvoicePagerAdapter salesInvoicePagerAdapter;

    private SalesInvoiceViewModel salesInvoiceViewModel;

    private Activity parentActivity;

    private AuthorityVerification authorityVerification;

    @Inject
    public SharedPreferencesRepository sharedPreferencesRepository;

    @Inject
    public SubscriptionPlanService subscriptionPlanService;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("Tab", "CHECKING...");
        daggerComponent.inject(this);
        dataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_sales_invoice, container, false);
        salesInvoiceViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new CostomaViewModelFactory((CostomaApplication) getActivity().getApplication())).get(SalesInvoiceViewModel.class);
        authorityVerification = new AuthorityVerification(requireActivity());

        parentActivity = getActivity();
        return dataBinding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        dataBinding.salesInvoiceFragmentTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(dataBinding.salesInvoiceFragmentViewPager);
        salesInvoicePagerAdapter = new SalesInvoicePagerAdapter(this, salesInvoiceViewModel);
        dataBinding.salesInvoiceFragmentViewPager.setAdapter(salesInvoicePagerAdapter);

        Log.i("ONCRE", "START");

//        for(int i=0; i < salesInvoicePagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
//            Log.i("DeTitle", "PAGE TITLE");
//            Log.i("DeTitle: ", salesInvoicePagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i).toString());
//            //dataBinding.salesInvoiceFragmentTabLayout.addTab(dataBinding.salesInvoiceFragmentTabLayout.newTab().setText(salesInvoicePagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i)));
//            dataBinding.salesInvoiceFragmentTabLayout.getTabAt(i).setText(salesInvoicePagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i));
//        }


        if (!subscriptionPlanService.hasActiveSubscription()) {
            dataBinding.startSaleBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            dataBinding.noActiveSubLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            dataBinding.startSaleBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            dataBinding.noActiveSubLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            dataBinding.startSaleBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        setDisplayedViewsForActiveSalesCount(0);

        salesInvoiceViewModel.salesCountChangedAlert.observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@NonNull Integer totalActiveSales) {
                Log.i("Set Current", String.valueOf(salesInvoicePagerAdapter.getCount()));

                if (totalActiveSales > 0) {
                    // dataBinding.salesInvoiceFragmentTabLayout.addTab(dataBinding.salesInvoiceFragmentTabLayout.newTab().setText(salesInvoicePagerAdapter.getPageTitle(totalActiveSales - 1)));
                    for(int i=0; i < salesInvoicePagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                        // Log.i("DeTitle", "PAGE TITLE");
                        // Log.i("DeTitle: ", salesInvoicePagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i).toString());
                        //dataBinding.salesInvoiceFragmentTabLayout.addTab(dataBinding.salesInvoiceFragmentTabLayout.newTab().setText(salesInvoicePagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i)));
                        dataBinding.salesInvoiceFragmentTabLayout.getTabAt(i).setText(salesInvoicePagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i));
                    }
                    dataBinding.salesInvoiceFragmentViewPager.setCurrentItem(totalActiveSales - 1);

//                    if (dataBinding.salesInvoiceFragmentTabLayout.getTabCount() == 2) {
//                        dataBinding.salesInvoiceFragmentTabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
//                    } else {
//                        dataBinding.salesInvoiceFragmentTabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
//                    }
                }
                setDisplayedViewsForActiveSalesCount(totalActiveSales);
                setActivityTitle(totalActiveSales);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setDisplayedViewsForActiveSalesCount(int activeSalesCount) {
        if (activeSalesCount > 0) {
            dataBinding.salesInvoiceFragmentViewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            dataBinding.salesInvoiceFragmentBlankSales.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            dataBinding.salesInvoiceFragmentViewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            dataBinding.salesInvoiceFragmentBlankSales.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        salesInvoiceViewModel.commitActiveSales();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.start_sale_btn:
                showAddSaleDialog();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.sales_invoice_menu, menu);

        boolean currentPdfGenerationValue = sharedPreferencesRepository.getBooleanValue(SharedPreferenceKeys.GENERATE_PDF_FOR_INVOICE);
        boolean currentMerchantReceiptValue = sharedPreferencesRepository.getBooleanValue(SharedPreferenceKeys.PRINT_MERCHANT_COPY_FOR_RECEIPT);

        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_invoice_pdf_generation_setting).setChecked(currentPdfGenerationValue);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_invoice_merchant_copy_receipt).setChecked(currentMerchantReceiptValue);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_item_create_sales_instance:
                if (!subscriptionPlanService.hasActiveSubscription()) {
                    ToastUtils.showLongToast(requireActivity(), "You do not have an active subscription!");
                    return true;
                }
                showAddSaleDialog();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_item_invoice_pdf_generation_setting:
                boolean generateInvoice = !item.isChecked();
                item.setChecked(generateInvoice);
                sharedPreferencesRepository.saveBooleanValue(SharedPreferenceKeys.GENERATE_PDF_FOR_INVOICE, generateInvoice);
                break;
            case R.id.menu_item_invoice_merchant_copy_receipt:
                boolean printMerchantReceipt = !item.isChecked();
                item.setChecked(printMerchantReceipt);
                sharedPreferencesRepository.saveBooleanValue(SharedPreferenceKeys.PRINT_MERCHANT_COPY_FOR_RECEIPT, printMerchantReceipt);
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void showAddSaleDialog() {
        NewSaleDialog dialog = new NewSaleDialog();
        dialog.setSalesInvoiceViewModel(salesInvoiceViewModel);
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), NewSaleDialog.FRAGMENT_TAG);
    }

    private void setActivityTitle(int totalSalesCount) {
        if (parentActivity != null) {
            if (totalSalesCount > 0) {
                parentActivity.setTitle(getString(R.string.menu_item_sales_invoice) + " - " + String.valueOf(totalSalesCount));
            } else {
                parentActivity.setTitle(R.string.menu_item_sales_invoice);
            }
        }

        parentActivity.getActionBar();
    }
}
```

I have tried everything i can to make it display well but is not working. I will welcome any assistance as i need to get this resolved now.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Please share you code snippet. are you using custom tabs?

Comment: How do you mean custom tabs